# How to handle to different ListViews using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have two ListViews in my Activity. I want to use Robotium to select a row in the second list View. When I use solo.clickonText(), it searches for the item on the first listview. How do I select a row in the second listview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on a particular line of your 2nd list view :

`solo.clickInList(int line, 1);`

If you want to click on a text in the 2nd list view :

```
while(!solo.searchText(text_to_click))
{
solo.scrollDownList(1);
}
solo.clickOnText(text_to_click);
```